# PHP for Native Client (NaCl)

Tags: php, lint, google-nativeclient

Are there any projects porting php to [native client](https://developers.google.com/native-client/)?
I haven't been able to find any.

My aim is to do php lint checking without having to make round-trips to the server.

Comment: I hope I answered your question below! I wasn't sure if you were targeting the open web, extension/app, or server use cases, so I tried to answer all of these.

Comment: have you looked at http://www.icosaedro.it/phplint/? or thought about doing it on command line with the php command?

Comment: Phplint doesn't help as it runs in PHP, The aim is to do lint checking in the browser without connecting to a server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using php.js to lint check PHP in the browser.
http://phpjs.hertzen.com/

PHP.js is a PHP vm written in Javascript. It works but is not a perfect solution as some of the syntaxes are out of date. An NaCl solution would probably be better as I assume it would be easier to maintain. But in the mean-time this is the best I could find.

Answer (score 3):

Answering @crystal-miller's revival of this question: I'm not aware of any PHP port to NaCl, but there are plenty of ports for other languages so the following information should point you in the right direction if you do want to port PHP (or any other language) to NaCl.

The NaCl team keeps a list of regression-tested ports in [naclports](https://code.google.com/p/naclports/wiki/PortList). These are all reasonably up to date, sometimes contain a small patch applied to the upstream project (though the team tries to upstream these patches), and have the right `make` incantation to build for the various NaCl and PNaCl targets (portable, x86-32, x86-64, ARM, static linking, dynamic linking, ...).

You'll want to start at [naclports](https://code.google.com/p/naclports/wiki/PortList) to see if your project is there. If you do get PHP working I suggest [contacting the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/group/native-client-discuss) and contributing your change.

The next tricky bit is whether you want to run the language:

- In the Chrome browser, on the open web.
- As a Chrome [extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) or [app](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps).
- On a machine e.g. a server.

The basic approach to compilation will be the same, but how the application communicates with the outside world will be entirely different: the sandbox exposes communication mechanisms to talk to processes outside the sandbox.

On the compilation side you can choose between targeting NaCl itself (which is architecture specific: x86-32/x86-64/ARM/MIPS) or PNaCl (architecture agnostic). Both are OS agnostic, and can execute as an extension/app or on a server, but only PNaCl can execute on the open web. The NaCl toolchain is based on GCC (as of writing 4.4 of x86, 4.9 for ARM), whereas the PNaCl toolchain is based on LLVM 3.5 (soon to be tip-of-tree). The PNaCl toolchain can also be used to target NaCl, this is somewhat complex at the moment but [should get much better soon with nacl-clang](https://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/issues/detail?id=3946). The NaCl toolchain supports static and dynamic linking (through newlib or glibc) as well as zero-cost C++ exception handling, whereas the PNaCl toolchain currently only supports static linking ([work in progress to add dynamic linking](https://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/issues/detail?id=3873)) and SJLJ-based exception handling (zero-cost to come later).

This sounds complicated, but overall it's just a compiler with a lot of knobs: distributing on the web requires speed and portability.

One thing to keep in mind: NaCl does support some limited dynamic code generation (e.g. there's a [Mono port](https://github.com/olonho/mono-elijah/tree/master/nacl) that uses JIT-compilation) but PNaCl currently doesn't. This means that interpreters are much easier to port (even V8 works in NaCl that way). Some languages like Halide, Rust or Julia generate LLVM bitcode, and it is possible to pass this bitcode to PNaCl but as of writing it's still sometimes tricky, follow the mailing list for updates on this (some people have gotten these to work). It is however possible to generate PNaCl's `.pexe` files dynamically, store them in the local filesystem, and execute them, and with dynamic linking you should be able to do the same with a `.pso`.

When executing as part of Chrome (the open web or extension or app) there are [APIs to communicate with the rest of Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/cpp-api). Some of the APIs require privileges, some are restricted to extensions/apps (because they don't fit the web's model), and some require the user to opt-in.

As part of Chrome you may also want to use [nacl_io](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/devguide/coding/nacl_io) which emulates even more POSIX behavior and allows you e.g. to mount an HTML5 filesystem and then just use regular POSIX APIs.

When running as a server things are more complicated: you have to figure out how to communicate with the outside world, and NaCl doesn't have default APIs. It is possible though: Google uses NaCl internally and there are projects like [ZeroVM](http://www.zerovm.org/) and Ripple Lab's [Codius Smart Contracts](https://github.com/codius/codius/wiki/Smart-Oracles:-A-Simple,-Powerful-Approach-to-Smart-Contracts) which do it. In these circumstances you may want to rely on NaCl's `sel_ldr` or `sel_ldr_seccomp` to execute the NaCl `.nexe` files (the `seccomp` version sets up a seccomp-based sandbox around the usual NaCl sandbox to do syscall filtering, I recommend doing this too). NaCl's and PNaCl's own test suites use `sel_ldr` to do regression testing.

With that in mind I think you have pointers to all the information you need to get started in any direction!

Answer (score 0):

[edit] I see what you're after now...  It would have been helpful to have posted a link to the google project page.

You may be at a point where you have to compile it yourself for NaCl.  I'm not sure that the original answer is actually useful, but I'm leaving it for posterity. :)

---

Use the [command line version of PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php).

You'll want to use the syntax check [option](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php)

```
-l               Syntax check only (lint)
```

**Full Reference**

```
Usage: php [options] [-f] <file> [--] [args...]
       php [options] -r <code> [--] [args...]
       php [options] [-B <begin_code>] -R <code> [-E <end_code>] [--] [args...]
       php [options] [-B <begin_code>] -F <file> [-E <end_code>] [--] [args...]
       php [options] -- [args...]
       php [options] -a

  -a               Run interactively
  -c <path>|<file> Look for php.ini file in this directory
  -n               No php.ini file will be used
  -d foo[=bar]     Define INI entry foo with value 'bar'
  -e               Generate extended information for debugger/profiler
  -f <file>        Parse and execute <file>.
  -h               This help
  -i               PHP information
  -l               Syntax check only (lint)
  -m               Show compiled in modules
  -r <code>        Run PHP <code> without using script tags <?..?>
  -B <begin_code>  Run PHP <begin_code> before processing input lines
  -R <code>        Run PHP <code> for every input line
  -F <file>        Parse and execute <file> for every input line
  -E <end_code>    Run PHP <end_code> after processing all input lines
  -H               Hide any passed arguments from external tools.
  -s               Output HTML syntax highlighted source.
  -v               Version number
  -w               Output source with stripped comments and whitespace.
  -z <file>        Load Zend extension <file>.

  args...          Arguments passed to script. Use -- args when first argument
                   starts with - or script is read from stdin

  --ini            Show configuration file names

  --rf <name>      Show information about function <name>.
  --rc <name>      Show information about class <name>.
  --re <name>      Show information about extension <name>.
  --rz <name>      Show information about Zend extension <name>.
  --ri <name>      Show configuration for extension <name>.
```