# Using PNaCl with node.js?

Tags: node.js, google-nativeclient

Is there anyway to use PNaCl or just [Google Native Client](https://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/) with node.js?

Comment: If you're just trying to run native code in your node application, you should write an [addon](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html).

Comment: im trying to write nativish code that a runs on the browser and node.js

Answer (score 1):

The V8 JavaScript engine can be configured to target NaCl and PNaCl (which node.js uses).

If you're trying to sandbox node.js outside of the browser then you may want to check out the [Codius](https://github.com/codius/codius/wiki/Smart-Oracles:-A-Simple,-Powerful-Approach-to-Smart-Contracts) paper.

If you want to use node.js inside a PNaCl/NaCl process inside Chrome then you may want to look at other [naclports](https://code.google.com/p/naclports/wiki/PortList) and [nacl_io](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/devguide/coding/nacl_io): in general PNaCl/NaCl support POSIX interfaces but they have to conform to the Web model, for example you need to mount the html5 filesystem before being able to do the usual read/write calls. This should work for a regular web page (using PNaCl) or for a Chrome app or extension.

I recently wrote a few more details pertaining to porting [PHP which may be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8477239/php-for-native-client-nacl/27989658#27989658). If you do get it working, please let the naclports folks know, and if something breaks do let them know too!